Problem with google login using react native
I'm trying to implement google login on my project made with React Native, both for android and ios.
From how I wrote the code, the google API seems to work: I open the app, click "login with Google" and the google modal opens that makes you select the google account to log in.
The problem is that after selecting the account, the google modal closes and I am not redirected to the homepage, so I remain on the login page. Yet there is no error in my console, can anyone tell me if I have to specify the redirect or if I made a mistake in writing the instructions?
// ...other imports...
import { makeRedirectUri } from "expo-auth-session";
import * as Google from "expo-auth-session/providers/google";
import * as WebBrowser from "expo-web-browser";

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

type Props = {};

const Login = (props: Props) => {
  const { isLoggedIn, doLogin, ottieniTema }: any = useGlobal();
  const navigation: any = useNavigation();
  const [topShow, setTopShow] = useState(true);
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  // Google login:
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(null);
  const redirectUri = makeRedirectUri({
    scheme: "lemiefiabe",
  });

  const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
    androidClientId: "my-android-client-id",
    iosClientId: "my-ios-client-id",
    redirectUri,
    scopes: ["profile", "email"],
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (response?.type === "success") {
      const { authentication } = response;
      if (authentication?.accessToken) {
        getUserInfo(authentication.accessToken);
      }
    } else if (response?.type === "error") {
      console.error("Errore di autenticazione:", response.error);
    }
  }, [response]);

  const getUserInfo = async (accessToken: string) => {
    try {
      const userInfoResponse = await fetch(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo",
        {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` },
        }
      );
      const user = await userInfoResponse.json();
      setUserInfo(user);
      await doLoginWithGoogle(user);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Errore nel recupero delle informazioni utente: ", error);
    }
  };

  const doLoginWithGoogle = async (user: any) => {
    try {
      const res = await doLogin(user.email, null, "google", user.sub);
      if (res.success) {
        navigation.navigate("AccountSelection");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Errore durante il login con Google: ", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <LoginLayout>
          <View style={[baseStyle.flexColumn, { width: "100%", gap: 15 }]}>
            <Pressable
              style={[
                buttonStyle.transparentGrayLight,
                buttonStyle.bigGenericButton,
                { width: "80%" },
              ]}
              onPress={() => {
                promptAsync();
              }}
            >
              <Image
                style={{ width: 25, height: 25 }}
                source={require("../../assets/images/google_icon.png")}
              />
              <Text style={{ color: colorsNeutral.white }}>
                Accedi con Google
              </Text>
            </Pressable>
          </View>
      </LoginLayout>
    </>
  );
};

export default Login;


